# DB process runs in OS Linux getting error when runs from one user

Tags: linux, oracle, file-io

I am running a db process from OS Linux.
When runs from oracle user the process is fine.
When run from other user (ex -myuser) it is showing the below error.
File I//O error Create_Link: ORA-20500

I dont understand it is a OS problem or DB problem.
Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is thrown by the operating system, because a file I/O error is coming from the OS, of course, due to an Oracle command in this case, which tried to issue a write operation, but failed, either due to the thing to be created already existed or due to lack of rights.